# How to check if length of multiple lists are equal in Python?

Tags: python

I have multiple lists which should have equal length. But the data is coming from an unreliable source. I have to make sure the multiple lists are of equal length before I process them.
One way would be to calculate the length of all lists and put them in another list. See if all elements are equal.
Any other pythonic way to do it?

This worked!

```
if len(list_1) == len(list_2) == len(list_3) == len(list_4):
    #do stuff if all lists equal
```

Comment: Remove redundant parentheses and you will get "most pythonic" way to do it.

Comment: `if (len(list_1) == len(list_2) == len(list_3) == len(list_4)):` should have worked - if it didn't, you had some other bug.

Comment: What you posted should have worked, i.e. the `if` code should be executed if and only if all four lists have the same length.  As mentioned, the outer parentheses are unnecessary and abnormal Python style, but they should not affect the result.

Comment: Do you want to compare the length or the lists themselves?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica , You are right. The lists were already of different sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `all` function to check the first list length against all other lists lengths.

```py
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [2,3,4]
l3 = [5,6,7]

lists = [l1, l2, l3]

if all(len(lists[0]) == len(l) for l in lists[1:]):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: What if the number of lists are unknown. What will be the generic solutions to compare all lists without knowing in advance.

Comment: This will work for unknown number of lists